# How to show the Portable Document Format inside web view using flutter?

Tags: flutter

I need to show the web view page consists of multiple PDF links. By clicking the PDF link, it should open the PDF page. I am using the web view flutter plugin. In IOS, it is working fine. But in Android, PDF is not opening. Please help me to resolve this.

```
body: SafeArea( 
          child: WebView(            
            initialUrl: filePath,
            javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
            onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
              _webViewController = webViewController;
              _webViewController.clearCache();
             _webViewController.reload();
            },
          ), 
      )
```

Comment: Please could you post the relevant section of code?

Comment: @simon I have added the code.